# Some posts from users who are not "new" users (e.g., one with over 620 answers & about 18,000 rep.) ending up in the First Posts queue

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, review, timeline

The Math SE post [Do most numbers have exactly $3$ prime factors?](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3544034/602049) currently has 2 answers. The top of the [timeline](https://math.stackexchange.com/posts/3544034/timeline) for the question is

[image: Primes question timeline]

Note the question's user [SmallestUncomputableNumber](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/405780/smallestuncomputablenumber) has over 1,000 reputation and this was their 23rd question. Also, why were there 2 first post reviews?

I gave an answer, with the top of its [timeline](https://math.stackexchange.com/posts/3544067/timeline) showing

[image: My answer timeline]

However, at the time, I already had over 620 answers and a reputation of about 18,000.

Note I checked the links to find all 3 of these reviews seemed to have occurred for those particular posts. Also, for comparison, the timeline of the other [answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3547453/602049) from [Michael Stocker](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/118272/michael-stocker) doesn't show any First Post review events. Also, my previous answer & the next answer to this one don't show any First Post reviews being done on either of them.

As for general details of what should be going to a First Posts review queue, a couple of references are this [answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/161391/562482) to the FAQ [What are the review queues, and how do they work?](What are the review queues, and how do they work?), as well as [What are the criteria to be considered a "first answer"?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/136177/562482), although the latter is from about 7 1/2 years ago.

Comment: Gut feeling: any chance two accounts got merged?

Comment: @Jenayah It's an interesting idea. However, having two accounts merged definitely didn't happen to me at least.

Comment: Well, the "first post" is a link to the reviewand you should check them, those were review audits. The posts got selected as audits and reviewers had to pass them.

Comment: The review results "Review audit passed [..]" tell us that detail. Regarding *"none of them should have been put there"*, when they were normal reviews, then yes, but the system selected them as positive posts and put them into the "first post" queue to check if the reviewer pays attention. The poster will be anonymized as well, so the reviewer won't see the reputation anyway.

Comment: @Tom Thanks for your feedback. I realize now what was going on, but didn't read carefully enough earlier to see that.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

They were *not* being reviewed as first posts. They were being reviewed as *audits*. Certain posts are eligible to be automatically selected as "known good" tests that users in those queues need to pass to prove they are paying attention.

You can tell that a review was an audit by clicking through to it and looking at its completion:

[image: Review audit passed]

If it were a normal review, that would say "Completed" rather than "Review audit passed/failed".

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I didn't realize they were being used for auditing, but on looking at this again now, I should've seen it earlier.

Comment: It is also kinda obvious from the screenshot OP provided. It states "audit" in the orange box.

Comment: @Luuklag When I first read "audit", I just considered it meant that it was part of the checking & review system. For example, at Merriam-Webster's site, the second definition of [audit](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/audit) says "a methodical examination and review", which is basically what the review system does. In particular, I didn't originally connect the use of the word term "audit" there with the occasional tests done on reviewers, i.e., the "audit" reviews. However, as I stated in my comment above, it's now quite obvious to me.

Comment: @JohnOmielan I didn't try to set you on record for not understanding what happened. I merely wanted to point out that the way that is demonstrated in this answer is more cumbersome then it should be.

Comment: @Luuklag Thanks for explaining. I'm sorry for misunderstanding you. It's just that I'm somewhat embarrassed, and even a bit ashamed, I didn't understand this earlier.