# Meta Review (old style, not this new beta format) is not working properly for First Questions

Tags: support, edits, review

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [First question in Review isn't really a first question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/93431/first-question-in-review-isnt-really-a-first-question)

This list of 'first questions' appears to be listing more than one 'first' for a user, [Discount Gucci Unicorns](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/174847):

[image: Multiple listings of first questions]

Comment: Yeah, this has confused a few other people too... But it's first questionS - plural - from new users.

Comment: Makes sense @Shog9 , thanks. Sorry for not searching better for that duplicate first.

Comment: Fortunately for you, it's generally agreed that you can't be held responsible for your actions on MSO when you're distracted by glittering golden unicorns.